# play audio to only one speaker left/right from commandline using libvlc

Tags: vlc, libvlc

Is it possible to make vlc play audio to only one of the speakers left/right from commandline ?

Comment: I think you can change the audio settings from the OS you use. So, you program this through an OS-specific feature using its system library. I don't think VLC has a feature to control an audio speaker... it only has audio effect filters. Under Windows, VLC uses DirectShow interface to capture all A/V devices. So, you shall use DirectX library to control the audio interface directly.

Comment: I need to be able to run 2 processes playing vlc at the same time, one process will play the audio to the left speaker and the other to the right speaker. can this be done with DirectShow ? cant I change the balance played by vlc ( with one of the filters maybe ) ?

Comment: What you need is to control L&R audio channels which libVLC seems to expose them but is not present in VLC GUI. In VLC, it allows an audio track of a media to be in *stereo* or *mono* on **both** side of the audio channels for that media player instance. This can be done through `Audio -> Audio Channels` menu option while playing the media. I am not sure if you can specifically control either L or R audio channel via VLC GUI interface.

Comment: Actualy I am using libvlc ( not the VLC GUI ) with a .net wraper called Vlc.Dotnet. and when I try to set the channel using libvlc_audio_set_channel, nothing changes ( when I try to get the channel with libvlc_audio_get_channel I get 0 )

Comment: Check the forum topic for hints http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=87115

Comment: I read this topic and I still cant figure out what is wrong with my code, I am using 1.1.10 and the dotnet wraper is using the correct function signature ( libvlc_audio_get_channel gets a pointer to the playerInstance that was created using libvlc_media_player_new )

Comment: I think it is possible..
http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__audio.html

Comment: @ee. Ubuntu Linux too. You mentioned Windows, so I will mention Ubuntu Linux has a `Sound Setting` to adjust left/right speakers called `Balance`. (I still wish VLC did that natively to be sure it's working, but the System should override VLC correct?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If VLC Audio channels is not performing well the most you can do is open a ticket in VLC bug system.

If you can't wait until the issue is fixed just redirect the audio output to STDOUT and use a tool like [SOX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) to do the work for you.

Selecting a Particular Channel with sox:

```
sox stereo.wav -c 1 mono.wav avg -l
```

of course sox can work on streams and it's not restricted to files.

BTW, sox comes with play and record utilities that can do the actual playback. see the examples [here](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html)

Comment: streaming to stdout on windows: http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=57940

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/)? It can easily do this via "-af channels=...".